# Java Tree implementation parent and child concept

Tags: java, tree

my input strings

```
1. An atomizer comprising liquid supply and an atomizing assembly detachably connected
2. The atomizer according to claim 1, wherein
3. The atomizer according to claim 1, wherein
4. Apparatus as claimed in any of the foregoing claims, wherein 
5. Apparatus as claimed in claim 4, wherein
```

Condition

no 1 is a parent its independent

and no 2 is dependent with 1

and no 3 is dependent with 1

and no 4 is a independent

and no 5 is dependent with 4

my output should be like below order

```
1
    2
    3
4
    5
```

Let me know which data structure is best with my expected output

As of now i have completed to split the dependent and independent, further more please provide solution

```
for (int i = 1; i < claimList.getLength(); i++) {
    String dummy = claimList.item(i).getNodeValue();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile((".*\\bclaimed in claim\\b.*?"));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dummy);
    Boolean isAvailable = matcher.find();
    if (isAvailable) {
        dependentClaims.add("\n" + claimList.item(i).getNodeValue());
    } else {
        independentClaims.add("\n" + claimList.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're storing a tree-like structure (that isn't big enough to raise performance questions), the main question is how you want to access it: which directions do you need to traverse it, do you need to be able to pick out any element, do you need to operate on subtrees and so on. You need to answer these questions if you want a good quality answer.

Comment: @bizclop: thanks just only for grouping and display no need to traverse in the tree

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> claims = new TreeMap<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(("\\bclaim\\s+(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));

// org.w3c.Node uses zero-based indices too.
for (int i = 0; i < claimList.getLenth(); i++) {
    String text = claimList.item(i).getNodeValue();
    int claimNo = i + 1;
    // Or better take the claimno from the text:
    claimNo = Integer.parseInt(text.replaceFirst("(?s)^(\\d*).*$", "0$1"), 10);
    // (?s) matches dot `.` also with line breaks
    // 0$1 ensures a number
    if (claimNo == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    claims.put(claimNo, new TreeSet());

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int refClaimNo = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        if (!claims.containsKey(refClaimNo)) {
             claims.put(claimNo, new TreeSet());
        }
        claims.get(refClaimNo).add(claimNo);
    }
}

claims.entrySet().forEach((e) -> {
             System.out.println(e.getKey());
             e.getValue().forEach((c) -> {
                 System.out.println("    " + c);
             });
        });
```

This takes care of the referred claim having listed the referents (and not vice versa). And of course forward references, and multiple references.

In production code, one should ensure having org.w3c.Element as node and take the text contents of it. Also a Claim class or such probably would make sense.

Comment: Thanks its very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create node class and for each element specify its descendants.

```
class Node {
String value;
List<Node> descendants;
}
```